# How to make part of right part of SlidingPaneLayout transparent? I tried to use android:background="@android:color/transparent", but this doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't understand why `ConstaintLayout` with id "transparent" remains white.
I also tried use android:background="#00ffffff", make transparent all right side of `SlidingPanel` (id right_side).

I want to do so as in the standard calculator app.

[image: SlidingPanel is closed. White part should be transparent:(]
  [image: SlidingPanel is opened]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/digits_area"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttons"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1.5"/>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/digits_area"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="3">

                <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout 
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/digits"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/operations"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
                        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/operations"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/digits">
                        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <!--This part I want to make transparent-->
                        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/transparent_layout"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/content"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/content"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/secondaryLightColor"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="4"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/transparent_layout">
                        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to put into FrameLayout the main screen content and SlidingPaneLayout over it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="here goes the bottom non sliding main screen content. it takes the whole screen"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<!-- SlidingPaneLayout should be transparent - do not set background color -->
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- first view takes whole screen is empty transparent placeholder -->
    <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- this is the paned that will slide - no background color too -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/slidePane" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" >

        <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:background="#101010"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" android:text="HI" android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button"  android:text="TEST"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout></FrameLayout>
```

.
[image: Transparent SlidingPaneLayout]